# How can I count the number of times this function is called?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So my assignment(I have to use the while statement) was to make a number guessing game, part of that was to show the number of guesses the player had after they get the number right. I found something that I read is supposed to work but doesn't. here is my code.

```
#A text program that is a simple number guessing game.
import time
import random
#Setting up the A.I.
Number = random.randint(1,101)
def AI():
    B = AI.counter =+ 1
    Guess = int(input("Can you guess what number I'm Thinking of?: "))
    while Guess > Number:
        print("nope, to high.")
        return AI()
    while Guess < Number:
        print("Sorry, thats to low. try again!")
        return AI()
    while Guess == Number:
        print("Congragulations! you win! You guessed " + str(B) + " times")
        time.sleep(60)
        quit()
AI.counter = 0
AI()
```

Though when the player gets the number right it says that the player got it in one guess even when that's not the case.

Comment: If y method calls itself its called recursion - you do not need that here.

Comment: You appear to have confused `+=` with `=+`

Comment: I think you want `if`s instead of `while`s.

Comment: but when i use =+ it gives me a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use default arguments:

```
def AI(B=1):
    Guess = int(input("Can you guess what number I'm Thinking of?: "))
    while Guess > Number:
        print("nope, to high.")
        return AI(B + 1)
    while Guess < Number:
        print("Sorry, thats to low. try again!")
        return AI(B + 1)
    while Guess == Number:
        print("Congragulations! you win! You guessed " + str(B) + " times")
        time.sleep(60)
        return
```

And then call the function:

```
AI()
```

Also, you should really be using `if`s instead of `while`s here since the loops are run exactly once, but `while`s also work, so that's fine. Also, recursion might eat up your RAM, which just wastes resources, provided that you could've implemented the same thing as a loop, but your approach works, so that's fine too.

Answer (score 1):

You were pretty close @Simpson! Here's a slightly changed version that should give you what you're looking for :)

Let me know if you have any questions!

```
#A text program that is a simple number guessing game.
import random
#Setting up the A.I.
def AI():
    counter = 1
    number = random.randint(1,101)
    guess = int(input("Can you guess what number I'm Thinking of?: "))
    while guess != number:
        if guess < number:
            print("Sorry, thats to low. try again!")
        else:
            print("nope, too high")
        counter += 1
        guess = int(input("Can you guess what number I'm Thinking of?: "))

    print("Congragulations! you win! You guessed " + str(counter) + " times")
    time.sleep(60)
    quit()

AI()
```

Comment: Hey thanks but I have to use the while statement in this particular assignment. my bad I'll edit that in

Comment: Do you have to be using multiple while statements? There's still one in here?

Answer (score 1):

Without recursion - changed the whiles to ifs and added counter inside the method.

```
import time
import random

Number = random.randint(1,101)

def AI():
    B = 1
    Guess = int(input("Can you guess what number I'm Thinking of?: "))
    while True:
        if Guess > Number:
            print("nope, to high.")
        elif Guess < Number:
            print("Sorry, thats to low. try again!")

        if Guess == Number:
            print("Congragulations! you win! You guessed " + str(B) + " times")
            time.sleep(2)
            break # leave the while true

        # increment number
        B += 1   
        Guess = int(input("Can you guess what number I'm Thinking of?: "))
AI()
```

Answer (score 1):

Counting function calls is a perfect case for [function decorators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators), a very useful feature of Python. You can define your decorator as:

```
def call_counted(funct):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapped.count += 1  # increase on each call
        return funct(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapped.count = 0  # keep the counter on the function itself
    return wrapped
```

And then you can use it to decorate a function you wish to count calls to without dealing with the counter itself in your process flow:

```
import time
import random

secret_number = random.randint(1, 101)

@call_counted  # decorate your AI function with the aforementioned call_counted
def AI():
    current_guess = int(input("Can you guess what number I'm thinking of?: "))
    while current_guess > secret_number:
        print("Nope, too high. Try again!")
        return AI()
    while current_guess < secret_number:
        print("Sorry, that's too low. Try again!")
        return AI()
    while current_guess == secret_number:
        print("Congratulations! You win! You guessed {} times.".format(AI.count))
        time.sleep(60)
        quit()

AI()
```

I restyled your code a bit, but it's essentially the same.

I'd avoid recursion, tho, because this can be written much simpler and without the need to count function calls:

```
import time
import random

secret_number = random.randint(1, 101)

def AI():
    counter = 0
    while True:
        counter += 1
        current_guess = int(input("Can you guess what number I'm thinking of?: "))
        if current_guess > secret_number:
            print("Nope, too high. Try again!")
        elif current_guess < secret_number:
            print("Sorry, that's too low. Try again!")
        else:
            break
    print("Congratulations! You win! You guessed {} times.".format(counter))
    time.sleep(60)
    quit()

AI()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it generically with a function decorator that addes a call counter to any function to which it is applied:

(Note I also modified your code so it follows the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) more closely.)

```
""" A text program that is a simple number guessing game. """
import functools
import time
import random

def count_calls(f):
    """ Function decorator that adds a call count attribute to it and counts
        the number of times it's called.
    """
    f.call_count = 0
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        decorated.call_count += 1
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return decorated

# Setting up the A.I.
number = random.randint(1, 101)
# print('The number is:', number)  # For testing.

@count_calls
def AI():
    guess = int(input("Can you guess what number I'm thinking of?: "))
    while guess > number:
        print("Nope, too high.")
        return AI()
    while guess < number:
        print("Sorry, that's too low. Try again!")
        return AI()
    while guess == number:
        print("Congragulations! You win! You guessed " + str(AI.call_count) + " times")
        time.sleep(10)
        quit()

AI()
```